# Python code doesn't print anything, just gives code 0

Tags: python

so I'm very noobish, I got this python code that I found somewhere in my folders, because I started learning python a while ago, and I need this code for class today. Thing is, it doesn't print anything, it just indicates that there's no problem with it. Can you help me? I need to sc the code and sc the output, if you can guide me to what line of code im missing or anything really.. thanks

```
def square(n):
    word = int(raw_input('Enter number here: '))
    if len(word) > 0:
        squared = n ** 2
        print ("%d squared is %d" %(n,squared))
```

Comment: Are you somewhere calling this function you have defined?

Comment: Uhm, no? How do i do that :x? print (square)?

Comment: this will generate error I guess. object of type 'int' has no len(). 
`if len(word) > 0:`

Comment: That's true, I removed the int, uhm, I guess I'll change the len(word) to if number > 0 or something like that? Would that be more correct?

Comment: are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Using python 3, in visual studio

Comment: Please replace raw_input() with input()

Comment: Can you explain what the significance of the variable "word" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using Python 3, you need to replace `raw_input` with `input`. Secondly and most importantly, integer does not work with `len` function and you should compare your integer directly. To handle potential type mismatch, use following code (you can put it in a loop or do any other modifications)

```
def square():
    n = input('Enter number here: ')
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except TypeError:
        print("Input is not a number")
    else:
        if word > 0:
            squared = n ** 2
            print ("%d squared is %d" %(n,squared))

# Let's call the function
square()
```

By the way, I think calling integer variable `word` is not very self-descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it's waaay better than the one I used, thing is it still doesn't allow me to input a number when I run it. When I run it on Visual Studio, it opens the cmd prompt, says "Enter a key to continue" , any key pressed closes the window. I need to SC the output of the code too.

Comment: I tried Online Python Compilers, doesn't give me an answer. Can you suggest me what compiler to use? Or what do you use, so this can give me an output? @Michal Polovka

Comment: One important thing - do you call your `square` function anywhere in the code?

Comment: No, how do I call it? Just print square?

Comment: Marked as answer. I upvoted and it was "recorded" but not counted because I'm new to the forums.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
def square(n):
    number = int(input('Enter number here: '))
    if number > 0:
        squared = n ** 2
        print ("%d squared is %d" %(n,squared))
```

Comment: integers don't have len()

Comment: yes you are correct. But in this context the variable "word" is used as string.

Comment: This is still very wrong, the variable `number` is not squared, the numerical argument is